# SQL Server : searching value doesn't have entry in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has the following values:

```
ID | Name
---------------
 1 | Anavaras
 2 | Lamurep
```

I need a query which outputs the value which doesn't have entry in the table.

For e.g:

If my where clause contains `id in('1','2','3','4')`, should produce output has

```
3 |
4 |
```

for the above entries in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would put this into a "derived table" and use `left join` or a similar construct:

```
select v.id
from (values(1), (2), (3), (4)) v(id) left join
     t
     on t.id = v.id
where t.id is null;
```

Comment: Fixed the mistake in `Table valued constructor` hope you don't mind ;)

Comment: i am not good at querying.. but concept you used derived table and table value constructor are amazing..Is there any good web site to learn new concepts like this.?

Comment: @prdp . . . Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
"SELECT id FROM table WHERE name IS NULL"
```

I'd assume?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to split your `in` to a table. Sample split function is here:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[split] 
(
    @str varchar(max), 
    @sep char
)
RETURNS 
@ids TABLE 
(
id varchar(20)
)
AS
BEGIN
declare @pos int,@id varchar(20)

while len(@str)>0
begin
select @pos = charindex(@sep,@str + @sep)
select @id = LEFT(@str,@pos),@str = SUBSTRING(@str,@pos+1,10000000)
insert @ids(id) values(@id)
end 
    RETURN 
END
```

Then you can use this function.

```
select id from dbo.split('1,2,3,4,5',',') ids
left join myTable t on t.id=ids.id
where t.id is null
-- if table ID is varchar then '''1'',''2'',''3'''
```